Query last and first day of the month in the where clause
We are trying to get rows with a join query we would to get each record of each first and last day of the month
we are using mariaDB 10.4 on php myadmin
Query 1:
SELECT storing_eigenschappen.date, storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id, storing_warnings.raw_warning, storing_errors.raw_error
FROM storing_eigenschappen 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_warnings ON storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id = storing_warnings.traplift_id AND storing_eigenschappen.date = storing_warnings.date 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_errors ON storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id = storing_errors.traplift_id AND storing_eigenschappen.date = storing_errors.date 
WHERE storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id LIKE "UP-%" 
    AND DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = 1 
    AND DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = LAST_DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date)

Result 1: No records found

Query 2
SELECT storing_eigenschappen.date, storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id, storing_warnings.raw_warning, storing_errors.raw_error 
FROM storing_eigenschappen 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_warnings ON storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id = storing_warnings.traplift_id AND storing_eigenschappen.date = storing_warnings.date 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_errors ON storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id = storing_errors.traplift_id AND storing_eigenschappen.date = storing_errors.date 
WHERE storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id LIKE "TL-%" 
    AND (
        DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = 1 OR 
        DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = LAST_DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date)
    )

Result 2:

Array ( [date] => 2024-06-01 14:08:25.000000 [traplift_id] => TL-123456 [raw_warning] => [raw_error] => )


query 3:
SELECT storing_eigenschappen.date, storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id, storing_warnings.raw_warning, storing_errors.raw_error 
FROM storing_eigenschappen 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_warnings ON storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id = storing_warnings.traplift_id AND storing_eigenschappen.date = storing_warnings.date 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_errors ON storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id = storing_errors.traplift_id AND storing_eigenschappen.date = storing_errors.date 
WHERE storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id LIKE "UP-%" 
     AND (
        DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = 1 OR 
        DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = 31 OR 
        DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = 30 OR 
        DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = 29
    )

Result 3:

Array ( [date] => 2024-06-01 14:08:25.000000 [traplift_id] => TL-123456 [raw_warning] => [raw_error] => ) Array ( [date] => 2024-06-30 14:08:52.000000 [traplift_id] => TL-123456 [raw_warning] => [raw_error] => ) Array ( [date] => 2024-06-29 14:41:22.000000 [traplift_id] => TL-123456 [raw_warning] => [raw_error] => )`


Query 4:
we tried to add this to get the last day
DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(storing_eigenschappen.date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL -DAY(DATE_ADD(storing_eigenschappen.date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Result 4:
we got an error the the syntax was wrong from mariaDB

What exactly is your question? Are queries 1-3 correct, but you're just asking about query 4's syntax? Or are these not returning the expected results at all? An [mre] would be useful here (with test data) so we can easily replicate the queries on a site like https://www.db-fiddle.com/.

The Last_Day() function returns an entire date, not just the day number.
That means you want something like this:
SELECT es.date, es.traplift_id, w.raw_warning, e.raw_error
FROM storing_eigenschappen es
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_warnings w ON es.traplift_id = w.traplift_id AND es.date = w.date 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_errors e ON es.traplift_id = e.traplift_id AND es.date = e.date 
WHERE es.traplift_id LIKE 'UP-%' 
    AND es.date IN ( es.date - interval (day(es.date)-1) day, LAST_DAY(es.date) )


Function last_day returns date not day num.
with query 1
try
SELECT storing_eigenschappen.date, storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id, storing_warnings.raw_warning, storing_errors.raw_error
FROM storing_eigenschappen 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_warnings ON storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id = storing_warnings.traplift_id AND storing_eigenschappen.date = storing_warnings.date 
LEFT OUTER JOIN storing_errors ON storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id = storing_errors.traplift_id AND storing_eigenschappen.date = storing_errors.date 
WHERE storing_eigenschappen.traplift_id LIKE "UP-%" 
    AND ( DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date) = 1 
        or storing_eigenschappen.date = LAST_DAY(storing_eigenschappen.date)
        )

